# Сортировка TreeMap StringComparer.Ordinal

Tags: java, c#

Сортировка `TreeMap` по ключу в Java, также как в C# я сортировал массив:

```
list.Sort(StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

Нужна именно сортировка `StringComparer.Ordinal` из C#.

```
Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(//Что сюда вписать//);
```

Comment: ничего, по дефлоту сортировка идет по алфавиту

Comment: StringComparer.Ordinal дает сортировку Alexey, Ivan, Mihail, alexey, ivan

Comment: Функционал можно, через new Comparator

Answer (score 2):

Ничего не надо писать, сортировка по алфавиту стандартная для строк. Если не указана другая, то используется стандартная.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put("ivan","");
    map.put("Alexey","");
    map.put("Ivan","");
    map.put("alexey","");
    map.put("Mihail","");

    for (String s : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
Alexey
Ivan
Mihail
alexey
ivan
```

---

Если вам прямо принципиально что-то написать в скобках то можно написать так

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

либо так:

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));
```

либо ещё длиннее:

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```

Во всех 4-х случаях результат будет одинаковый

Comment: У меня почему-то не работает